# Writing an exist condition that breaks a while loop

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to write a "while" loop so the game will keep playing until any player's 4 win conditions are true. The players are stored as objects in an array, and also have an "active" key which tracks if it's their turn.

I've isolated everything that a player does on their turn in the takeTurn() function, but I'm trying to come up with a way to keep looping through the allPlayers array and giving each player a turn until the 4 win conditions are met. What should I do? I've tried writing a "newActivePlayer" function but it doesn't work within the while loop, because of scope problems I don't really understand yet.

```
var allPlayers = [player1, player2, player3, player4]
var activePlayer = player1;

while (!win) {
    takeTurn();
    if (activePlayer.wincondition1 === true && activePlayer.wincondition2 === true && activePlayer.wincondition3 === true && activePlayer.wincondition4 === true) {
        win = true;
    };
};
```

Comment: In Javascript, you should pretty much never do a loop like this because doing so means that the JS engine has no opportunity to process the event queue.  You will have to show us what actually happens in `takeTurn()` for us to know what to suggest, but probably you should be deciding what to do next from various event handlers - not looping.

Comment: Your true problem is in the design. Remove the while loop, and show us the takeTurn function

Answer (score 0):

This loop wouldn't give JS the breathing space it needed.

Whatever happens inside the `takeTurn()` function, you should return a [promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

This way you tell the browser *"execute takeTurn() and wait for my instructions"*

```
var activePlayer, i = 0;

takeTurn().then(promiseDone());  //Way to say "check conditions and launch again"

//This function checks the condition and call takeTurn() if game is still on
function promiseDone(){

   if (!activePlayer.wincondition1 || !activePlayer.wincondition2  || !activePlayer.wincondition3 || !activePlayer.wincondition4) {

        i === 3 ? i = 0 : i++   // see "ternary operators" if you don't get this   

        activePlayer = allPlayers[i]
        takeTurn().then(promiseDone());

    }
    else
       alert('Game over');

}
```

Comment: Something seems to be missing - when I run the program, the first player takes their turn and then it throws "Error: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined." Any idea why that would be?

Comment: You need to incorporate Promise mechanism into your program. Please study the link In have provided and see how it can help your game. Then you can use my solution to further understand how things should work,